# Magento 2 : Delete all Catalog Price Rules Programmatically

Tags: magento2, database

I know we have `Delete Rule` option when we edit any Catalog Price Rule. But I need to delete all Calalog Price Rules programmatically because there is no option to delete all rules.

Solutions may be :

- What if I truncate all the tables related to catalogrule and run `indexer:reindex`
- Programmatically delete all rules and run `indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Custom action to delete all the rules

Try following way:

```
use Magento\CatalogRule\Api\CatalogRuleRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection as RuleCollection;
use Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory as RuleCollectionFactory;
```

Di

```
public function __construct(
    CatalogRuleRepositoryInterface $catalogRuleRepository,
    RuleCollectionFactory $ruleCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->catalogRuleRepository = $catalogRuleRepository;
    $this->ruleCollectionFactory = $ruleCollectionFactory;
}
```

Now:

```
/** @var RuleCollection $ruleCollection */
$ruleCollection = $this->ruleCollectionFactory->create();
foreach ($ruleCollection as $rule) {
    $this->catalogRuleRepository->deleteById($rule->getId());
}
```

OR

> Truncate all Catalog Price Rule tables

```
/** @var array List of all the Catalog Price Rule tables */
public $catalogrule_tables = [
    "catalogrule",
    "catalogrule_customer_group",
    "catalogrule_group_website",
    "catalogrule_group_website_replica",
    "catalogrule_product_price",
    "catalogrule_product_price_replica",
    "catalogrule_product",
    "catalogrule_product_replica",
    "catalogrule_website"
];
```

Comment: Thanks Sohel Rana. What if we programmatically truncate all the catalogrule tables ? Will it be fast as well ?

Comment: If any thirdparty module uses any event then this way well be safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_customer_group`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_group_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_group_website_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_product_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_product_price_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_product_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_website`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```